# Get house number formats with regex

Tags: regex

I am struggeling to find the right regex to match with certain house number formats:

Following formats shall be found:

1 / 1a / 1a-z

What should not match is something like: 1 Building 1

So far I got `'^\d[A-Za-z]?[-]?[A-Za-z]?$'`  which works for all cases but also matches 1ab.

So how can I add the requirement of having only 1 letter after the digit?

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. **You start it, and then we help. We don't write it for you.** Show us the actual code that you've tried, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Comment: Try `^\d([A-Za-z]([-][A-Za-z])?)?$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the regular expression you are aiming for is something along the lines of `^\d+([A-Za-z](-[A-Za-z])?)?$`

I'll break this down:

- `\d` represents any digit
- the `+` means *1 or more of* (so `\d+` matches 1, 12, 123, etc.)
- the parentheses `(` and `)` contain a group
- `?` means *zero or one of*
- `[A-Za-z]` matches any character in the ranges `A-Z` or `a-z`
- `[A-Za-z](-[A-Za-z])?` means *a letter, optionally followed by a hyphen and another letter*

For a visualisation, see [here](https://regexper.com/#%5E%5Cd%2B%28%5BA-Za-z%5D%28-%5BA-Za-z%5D%29%3F%29%3F%24) (tool not mine)